# 'loggedInUser' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I am using Auth library to set current logged in user , I am able to obtain loggedInUser object in console , but when i check any conditions with loggedInUser , it says this error :

'loggedInUser' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)

here's the code :

```
const UserList: FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <KTCard>
        <KTCardBody className='py-4'>
          <PaginatedItems />
        </KTCardBody>
      </KTCard>
    </>
  )
}

const MainWrapper: FC = () => {
  const intl = useIntl()
  const { loggedInUser }= useAuth()
  console.log(loggedInUser) // Here  I am able to retrieve loggedInUser object details with id , name , token , role , etc .... Hence its working here.

  return (
    <>
    {loggedInUser.role !== 'superAdmin' ? ( // Here is says 'loggedInUser' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)
      <> 
          <ErrorsPage />
      </>
    ) : (
      <> 
       <PageTitle breadcrumbs={[]}> Menu Items </PageTitle>
      <UserList />
      </>
    )}
    </>
  )
}

export { MainWrapper }
```

Comment: Try  `loggedInUser && loggedInUser.role !== 'superAdmin'` or `loggedInUser?.role`

Comment: Try `const { loggedInUser }= useAuth()  || {}`

Comment: yes this worked out ! thanks kiranvj !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when `useAuth()` returned undefined. Then we cannot destructure it.

Another scenario is `useAuth()` return any empty object which dont have a key/prop`loggedInUser`. Give validation to handle this

```
loggedInUser && loggedInUser.role !== 'superAdmin'
```

or  (using [optional chaining](https://kiranvj.com/blog/blog/optional-chaining-in-es7-and-support-in-react-js))

```
loggedInUser?.role
```

and

```
const { loggedInUser }= useAuth()  || {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that there is no guarantee for `loggedInUser` to be properly defined. So, even though you see it being properly defined at `console.log`, the initialization of

```
const { loggedInUser }= useAuth()
```

does not guarantee that `loggedInUser` will have a proper value. You can use `loggedInUser?.role` to remedy this problem.